# How to formalize the groups axioms in a first order language?

Tags: first-order-logic

I'm having trouble to formalize in FOL with equality, the statement

"Every element has a multiplicative inverse" 
or

"For every $x$ there's a $y$ such that $xy = e$ where $e$ is some identity.

The problems comes in with the identity. I tried to formalize as
$ \forall x(\exists y( xy = x \wedge yx = x) \rightarrow \exists z(xz = y \wedge zx = y))$

is that correct?

Comment: Do you mean the [*identity element* axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition) ? : "There exists an element e in G such that, for every element a in G, the equation e • a = a • e = a holds:" $\exists e \forall x (ea=a \land ae=a)$

Comment: No Mauro, the inverse element axiom.

Comment: "For each $a \in G$, there exists an element $b \in G$, commonly denoted $a^{-1}$, such that $a b = b a = e$, where $e$ is the identity element." $∃e[∀x(ea=a ∧ ae=a) ∧ ∀x∃y(xy=e ∧ yx=e)]$.

Comment: Thank you Mauro.